# Drawing horizontal or vertical lines won't get drawn on the surface. Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

Have this problem of a line not getting drawn. But only it it's perfectly vertical or horizontal.

Say i have points A{ 400, 300 } and B{ 400, 200 }. Now if I try to draw a line between these points it doesn't find it's way on the screen.

If i however change the point A to be positioned at { 401, 300 } the program runs as i would intend it to run.

Is there a clear reason why straight horizontal or vertical lines doesn't get drawn? And a way to circumvent that? Don't wanna tilt all the straight lines.

Part of the pipeline-setup:

```
inputAssembly.topology = vk::PrimitiveTopology::eLineStrip;
rasterInfo.polygonMode = vk::PolygonMode::eLine;
```

using VulkanSDK 1.0.42.1 on intel igpu.

Edit:
Okay if i raise linewidth over 1.f on rasterizer it will draw. However not every gpu is capable of doing that. But atleast a temporal quirk.

Comment: My guess is that a line of width 1.0 that is vertical or horizontal with end points at integer coordinates lines up exactly between framebuffer pixels... But even then, the rasterization rules should guarantee that something gets drawn...

Answer (score 0):

(I know it's a very old post, but no answer provided. ;-)).

In case of the lines wider than 1.0f - You are allowed to draw such lines only if You enable wideLines feature and You can enable it only when it is supported by a physical device You are using. Without enabling this feature, You can't provide values other than 1.0 for line width during pipeline creation. So even if it works, it can only be a temporary solution because You are violating the specification.

This kind of behavior suggests it's a bug in a driver. Try the latest version (if You didn't do it already) and if it doesn't help contact Intel's support and submit a bug (if You didn't do it already ;-)).